# Managing python project CI/CD with Conda, Poetry and pip

Tags: python, continuous-integration, github-actions, conda, python-poetry

I have read through a couple of dozens of writeups on how to equip a modern python project to automate linting, testing, coverage, type checking etc (and eventually deploy it on cloud servers. Not interested in the latter part yet.)

I am thinking about using **conda** as my environment manager. This would give me the advantage of being able to install non python packages if needed and also by creating the project environment with a specified python version I believe it would replace **pyenv**.

Within the newly conda created environment I would use **poetry** to manage dependencies and to initialize its TOML and add other needed python packages which would be installed by **pip** from PyPI.

Did I get the above right?

To complete the "building" phase I am also looking into using **pytest** and **pytest-cov** for code coverage, **mypy/pydantic** for type checking and **black** for formatting.

All of this should work both on my local development machine but then when I push on **GitHub** trigger an **Action** and perform the same checks, so that any contributor will go through them. Currently managed to do it for pylint, pytest and coverage for very simple projects without requirements.

Does all of this make sense? Am I missing some important component/step? For example I'm trying to understand if tox would help me in this workflow by automating testing on different python versions, but haven't come to grips integrating this flood on (new to me) concepts. Thanks

Comment: I've not used conda, but the rest sounds solid. You can add tox if you want your code to be compatible with different versions of python

Comment: Thanks a lot @Matthias. I would use Conda only to create environments with the specific python version, while poetry/pip would do dependency resolution and installs. Will have to understand tox in this context. Take care.